# magento2 enable SOAP

Tags: magento2

how do I enable SOAP on Magento2?

If I access http://example.com/soap?wsdl&services=customerV1 I get

```
[2015-04-24 05:47:01] main.CRITICAL: exception 'RuntimeException' with message 'Report ID: webapi-5539d8d5c0c57; Message: Requested service is not available: "customerV1"' in /srv/vhosts/magento2/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php:194
Stack trace:
#0 /srv/vhosts/magento2/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php(139): Magento\Framework\Webapi\ErrorProcessor->_critical(Object(RuntimeException))
#1 /srv/vhosts/magento2/html/var/generation/Magento/Framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor/Proxy.php(95): Magento\Framework\Webapi\ErrorProcessor->maskException(Object(RuntimeException))
#2 /srv/vhosts/magento2/html/app/code/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Soap.php(171): Magento\Framework\Webapi\ErrorProcessor\Proxy->maskException(Object(RuntimeException))
#3 /srv/vhosts/magento2/html/app/code/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Soap.php(129): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Soap->_prepareErrorResponse(Object(RuntimeException))
#4 /srv/vhosts/magento2/html/var/generation/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Soap/Interceptor.php(122): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Soap->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#5 /srv/vhosts/magento2/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Http.php(115): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Soap\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#6 /srv/vhosts/magento2/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Bootstrap.php(245): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#7 /srv/vhosts/magento2/html/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#8 {main} [] []
```

I'm running 0.74.0-beta5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that problem in service name.
Try use this URI: 
http://example.com/soap?wsdl&services=customerCustomerRepositoryV1

Comment: \Magento\Webapi\Model\Soap\Config::getServiceName is where the Soap Service name is computed. The docblock examples need to be updated to add the new \Api\ contracts path.

Comment: Is there any official documentation on the official names? The official documentation points to "http://example.com/soap?wsdl&services=customerV1", which gives the error mentioned by @webunicorn.